# How to add a View to a ViewFlipper while it has been set an Adapter ? (The specified child already has a parent)

Tags: android, view, adapter

I'm making a `GridView` to dynamically contain a set of clickable icons, so I need to set an Adapter on this `GridView`, and add a Listener.

`mGridView = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.listbody);

        mGridView.setAdapter(new ListAppAdapter());

        mGridView.setOnItemClickListener(this);`

And I'd wrote the Adapter myself:

`class ListAppAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

...

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {...}

...

}`

Now I need this `GridView` to slide from side to side by gesture, so I tried `ViewFlipper`:

`mFlipper = (ViewFlipper) mInflate.inflate(R.layout.main, (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.ViewFlipper));

        mFlipper.addView(mGridView);

        mDetector = new GestureDetector(this);`

BUT I got an Exception:

`The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.`

Then I tried to wrap the `GridView` in another `FrameLayout` in the XML and add the `FrameLayout` to the`ViewFlipper`, The fling gesture was captured but the `GridView` didn't show up, I was Flinging the blank `FrameLayout`!

Anyone know how to deal with this ?

The XML and Layout parameters are all right, when I add a simple `ImageView` to the 'ViewFlipper', it works.

And I've tried to remove all child views of the `ViewFlipper` and didn't add the same instance of the `GridView`. But when I add the `GridView`, the Exception still comes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your GridView already have a parent view in your layout xml. and you are trying to add that again in ViewFlipper. its not possible to do that. So you have to make GridView dynamically and then add it in ViewFlipper or you can also inflate a grid view from xml. it will work.

Comment: Thank you, I found that adding the FrameLayout containing the GridLayout actually works, but I can only drag on the banks parts, if I drag on an icon, it would be clicked..

Comment: you have to use touchListener instead of clickListener and manage click event using ACTION_DOWN and ACTION_UP .Use Timer to handle it.